# Proportionally Distributing $N$ items across $B$ bins.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, closed-form, mathematical-modeling

My question is similar to this: [Proportional Distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764373/proportional-distribution/1764397#1764397?newreg=a1c95b683375405e85e867f4aea98aa8)

My problem follows: I have $N$ items that cannot be broken up into fractional components, but should be distributed across $B$ bins where each bin has capacity of $b_i$ for $b_i \in B$.

My goal is to create a closed-form equation representing how many items are distributed to each bin assuming that the N items are fairly distributed across the bins.

One naive method I've considered was distributing $\left\lfloor \dfrac {b_i} {\sum _{k \in B} b_k} N \right\rfloor$ across all bins. And then give $1$ to the first $x$ bins where $x$ is the remaining items.

Is there a better way to describe this naive equation? Possibly using floor and ceiling, instead. Alternatively, is there a better way to describe $x$?

Or are there any other methods of fairly distributing the items that have a solid equational representation?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr

This is a well known problem with several suggested solutions each of which can be characterized as fair or unfair depending on your definition of "fair". Some have formulas, others are algorithms that work from the data.

Here are some of many links to the literature, focused on the application of your problem to the apportionment of seats in congress.

It's not an answer to your question but you may find it useful or informative.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apportionment_paradox

https://books.google.com/books?id=KC76Bm13NogC&dq=determining+seats+in+congress+american+mathematical+monthly&source=gbs_navlinks_s

http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/apportioning-representatives-in-the-united-states-congress-hills-method-of-apportionment

http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/apportioning-representatives-in-the-united-states-congress-jeffersons-method-of-apportionment

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CongressionalApportionmentUsingGeneralDivisorMethods/

Comment: The issue with the Jefferson and hills method seems they sometimes assign  N+1 items in total, rather than N items. The Hamilton method seems to be the one that I described above with the exception of instead of the first x bins, it's x bins ordered by their fractional component. Are there any other algorithms that can round conservatively to never exceed N?

Comment: @mattsap For other algorithms and their advantages and disadvantages I suggest following links from the links I've provided - this isn't really my area of expertise - I just happen to have seen some of those articles when they came out and searched for them now. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: I've looked into it further. Apparently, there are some methods that do not violate the quota rule, but the hamilton method seems to be the most preferred. Thanks for helping me reach this conclusion. I may modify the hamilton method to be able to analyze a little bit better. Seems the bounty can only be awarded after 24 hours. I'll update later. =)